# How to make flexbox distribute items evenly without misalignment of siblings?

Tags: css, flexbox, centering

I'm trying to recreate the dragon balls from Dragon Ball. I need to distribute the stars evenly across the center of the "ball" using flexbox and I need to center the balls to the parent container. The issue is that when the ball with 4 or more stars is next to a ball with fewer stars, the 4-star ball shifts up and misaligns compared to the previous ball. The stars must be centered vertically and horizontally inside the ball. The balls must be aligned from the top no matter what order they have inside the parent div.

```css
.circulo_iconos{
        width: 8em;
        height: 8em;
        border: 1pt solid black;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: inline-flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .circulo_iconos .fa{
        font-size: 2em;
    }
    .circulo_iconos .fa.fa-star{
        color: yellow;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <div id="tiene_circulos">
     <div class="circulo_iconos" data-number="1">
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
     </div>
     <div class="circulo_iconos" data-number="2">
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
     </div>
     <div class="circulo_iconos" data-number="3">
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
     </div>
     <div class="circulo_iconos" data-number="4">
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
      <br />
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
     </div>
     <div class="circulo_iconos" data-number="5">
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
     </div>
     <div class="circulo_iconos" data-number="6">
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I only made the parent container flex with flex-wrap and think that pretty much solved it. Did it?

```css
/* * * I only added this * * */  
#tiene_circulos {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.circulo_iconos{
      width: 9em;
      height: 9em;
      border: 1pt solid black;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 50%;
      display: inline-flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      /*But it would look even better with those 2 lines below I think ^^*/     
      /* padding: 1em;
      margin:1em;*/
  }
  .circulo_iconos .fa{
      font-size: 2em;
  }
  .circulo_iconos .fa.fa-star{
      color: yellow;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <div id="tiene_circulos">
     <div class="circulo_iconos" data-number="1">
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
     </div>
     <div class="circulo_iconos" data-number="2">
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
     </div>
     <div class="circulo_iconos" data-number="3">
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
     </div>
     <div class="circulo_iconos" data-number="4">
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
      <br />
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
     </div>
     <div class="circulo_iconos" data-number="5">
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
     </div>
     <div class="circulo_iconos" data-number="6">
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: So I just Googled what the dragonballs balls are supposed to look like () and I'm thinking you might be better off with absolute positioning for the stars themselves if you want the perfect result.
I could post another answer with a small demo if you like...

Comment: What you did is exactly what I needed. I'm new with flexbox. You are a lifesaver!